# Locating Child element of the web element from a list of elements for android application using selenium xpath

Tags: listview, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selendroid, android-uiautomator

I am locating element for android application and have one query. I am storing list of web elements as below

```
List<WebElement> trackingsList =  tracking.getTrackingElements();
```

getTrackingElements() is function that is returning list of WebElements and is returning elements fine, this is checked.
now I want to get a child element of the webelement at position trackingList.get(0) using xpath.
[image]
so i tried like

```
trackingsList.get(0).findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout"))
```

but it is not working. any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the targeted element by class name :

```
trackingsList.get(0).findElement(By.className("android.widget.LinearLayout"));
```

And by tag name:

```
trackingsList.get(0).findElement(By.tagName("LinearLayout"));
```

Comment: Thank @florent-b for reply.. but i am getting this error after using this.. "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: Cannot use xpath locator strategy from an element. It can only be used from the root element) "

Comment: Have you tried with the by class name? : trackingsList.get(0).findElement(By.className("android.widget.LinearLayout"));